# prevent removing archives from SourceFolder when extract files

Tags: batch, rar

I use this script to extract `.rar` files

```
@echo off

set "SourceFolder=C:\temp"
set "TargetFolder=C:\temp2"
if not exist "%TargetFolder%" md "%TargetFolder%"

"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -ad -cfg- -idq -r -y "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" "%TargetFolder%"

del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar">nul
for /D %%D in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do rd "%%D" 2>nul
```

But it removes `.rar` archives from `SourceFolder`
Is there a way to prevent this removal action?

Comment: What do you think this line `del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar">nul` does?

Comment: yes, I see now, sorry, I removed `del`

Comment: You need to remove the whole line :)

Comment: ah, ok, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off

set "SourceFolder=C:\temp"
set "TargetFolder=C:\temp2"
if not exist "%TargetFolder%" md "%TargetFolder%"

"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -ad -cfg- -idq -r -y "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" "%TargetFolder%"

for /D %%D in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do rd "%%D" 2>nul
```

- The solution is to remove the 6th line:

```bat
del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar">nul
del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar">nul
```

Comment: You don’t need `if exist ....` use **`2>nul md "%TargetFolder%"`**. If folder exist, no error/warning will appear on your screen. If folder do not exist, will be create.

Comment: I don't know @ItWasn'tMe.. you aren't wrong but this is a matter of opinion.  You are saying "let it error rather than check if it is going to".. this might be fine for `md` but isn't a good practice to teach people.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Is the same results with one action, test to see. Obs.: I don’t know if I get the message too!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It may or may not be a good practice, I didn't see anything mentioned yes / no, but it also teaches how to predictively use / treat a potential error, where the worst result is just a message, nothing more, a line, and it can be hidden in execution ..

Comment: Fair enough @ItWasn'tMe !! Clearly we both get it :)

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off

if not exist "%TargetFolder%" md "%TargetFolder%"
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -ad -cfg- -idq -r -y "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" "%TargetFolder%"
```

---

> ***prevent removing archives from SourceFolder when extract files***
> If you need to prevent files from being deleted, remove the last 2 lines;

This line deletes ***all files*** recursively and omitting the output by `>nul`:

```bat
del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" >nul
del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" >nul
```

This line remove **folders** also omitting ***any error in output*** by `2>nul`:

```bat
for /D %%D in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do rd "%%D" 2>nul
for /D %%D in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do rd "%%D" 2>nul
```

You don’t need `if exist "%TargetFolder%"`, use `2>nul md "%TargetFolder%"`, if the folder exist, no error/warning will appear on your screen, and if the folder do not exist, will be created.

```bat
2>nul md "C:\temp2\."
```

---

**Obs.: 1** As yours `SourceFolder` and `TargetFolder` folders have apparently short paths, you can optionally use them instead of creating variables with length greater than the path itself, making it simpler and easier to read.

```bat
@echo off

2>nul md "C:\temp2\."
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -ad -cfg- -idq -r -y "C:\temp\*.rar" "C:\temp2"
```

**Obs.: 2** The last line is not doing anything, it is a loop that goes through the folders to remove them, without adding `/S` in `rd "%%D"` the command does not remove folders with files inside, where in the original code, the command on the previous line removed those files recursively before the `For /D`, now it doesn't make sense, other than the error message `The directory is not empty.` be omitted by `2>nul`.

[image]

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`RD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`For /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [`MD`|`MKDir`](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)
- [`Rar.exe /?`](https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/english.html)
- [`WinRar.exe /?`](https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/english.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)